# gunicorn, nginx, and using port 80 for running a django web application

Tags: django, nginx, port, gunicorn

I have django, nginx, and gunicorn installed on a web server.

Nginx listens on port 80
Gunicorn runs django project on port 8000

This works fine. If I go to www.mysite.com:8000/myapp/ the django application comes up OK. But what if I want users to go to www.mysite.com/myapp/ to view the django application? I don't think getting rid of Nginx is the answer, and I'm hoping I missed some configuration tweak i can apply to make this work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, getting rid of nginx is definitely not the answer. The answer is to follow the [very nice documentation](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/19.1.1/deploy.html) to configure nginx as a reverse proxy to gunicorn.

Comment: awesome thanks. I've been following other tutorials that I completely skipped gunicorn's own one. It works perfect.

Comment: I wonder what the "very nice documentation" said?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following configuration, so you can access your website normally on port 80:

this is your nginx configuration file, `sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/django`

```
upstream app_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
    }
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        client_max_body_size 250M;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 15;

# Your Django project's media files - amend as required
        location /media  {
            alias /home/xxx/yourdjangoproject/media;
        }
        # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        location /static {
            alias /home/xxx/yourdjangoproject/static;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
```

and configure gunicorn as

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]
# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn
setuid yourdjangousernameonlinux
setgid yourdjangousernameonlinux
chdir /home/xxx/yourdjangoproject

exec gunicorn \
    --name=yourdjangoproject \
    --pythonpath=yourdjangoproject \
    --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    yourdjangoproject.wsgi:application
```